# What is a good way to check for a winner in Tic Tac Toe using a for loop, then switch players?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to check for a winning condition using a for loop. Basically I want to have a function that can be called each time a player clicks a cell. Then switch players so the computer makes an entry after the human player with a min max function. So far my program is able to push the cell id as a string from the human player to the huPlayerArr then display it on screen. The desired outcome would be to do the same for the computer player next.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var huPlayer, computer;
  var huPlayerArr = [], computerArr = [];
  var occupiedCells = [];
  var winningCombos = [
    [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],[1,5,9],[3,5,7]
  ];

  $cell = $('.cell');

  $('#myModal').modal('show');

  $('.select').click(function() {
    let turnX = 'X';
    let turnO = 'O';
    $(this).attr("data-dismiss", "modal");
    huPlayer = $(this).text() 
    computer = huPlayer === turnX ? turnO: turnX; 
    $('.player').append(`<div class="alert-success">You chose to play as ${huPlayer}</div>`);
  });

  function resetGame() {
    huPlayer = undefined;
    computer = undefined;
    huPlayerArr = [];
    computerArr = [];
    occupiedCells = [];

  }

  function generateRandomNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
  }

  function isEmpty(el) {
    if ($.trim($(el).html()) == '') {
      return true;
    };
  }

  function insertMarker(text, val, id) {
    occupiedCells.push(+id);
    text.html(val);
  }

  function isThereAWinner(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < winningCombos.length; i++) {
      if (arr.includes( winningCombos[i][0] )
        && arr.includes( winningCombos[i][1] )
        && arr.includes( winningCombos[i][2] )) { 
        console.log("There's a winner");
      } 
    }
  }

  $cell.click(function() {
    if (huPlayer === undefined && computer === undefined) {
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    } 
    else {
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      if (isEmpty(id)) {
        insertMarker($(this), huPlayer, id);
        huPlayerArr.push(id);
        console.log(huPlayerArr); 

        if (isThereAWinner(huPlayerArr)) {
          console.log("There's a winner");
        }
        else if (occupiedCells.length === 9) {
          console.log("Tie game");
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
  <header>
    <h1 class="text-center">Tic Tac Toe</h1>
    <div class="player text-center"></div>
  </header>

  <div id="popup-box">
    <div class="modal fade bg-red" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title text-center text-danger">Welcome!</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <h1 class="text-center text-success">Choose X or O !!!</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="select btn btn-info btn-lg">X</button>
            <button type="button" class="select btn btn-danger btn-lg">O</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="app">

      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="cell" id="cell-0"></td>
          <td class="cell" id="cell-1"></td>
          <td class="cell" id="cell-2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="cell" id="cell-3"></td>
          <td class="cell" id="cell-4"></td>
          <td class="cell" id="cell-5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="cell" id="cell-6"></td>
          <td class="cell" id="cell-7"></td>
          <td class="cell" id="cell-8"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Does what you have so far do what you expect? If so, can you ask a more specific question? If not, what errors or unintended results do you get?

Comment: **Hint:** First, write a function that compares two three-element arrays for equality.

Comment: So far I am able to get the cell id when a user clicks on the html element. Each cell has an id. The cell id gets pushed to huPlayerArr. When I console log it says "winner" each time a user clicks rather than after three cells in a row have been clicked. This is my first time posting on Stack Overflow so I'm not sure the best way to ask.

Answer (score 0):

For every `winningCombos` array, if each of the three square IDs in that winning combo exists in `arr`, then you have a winner:

```
function isThereAWinner(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < winningCombos.length; i++) {
        if (
            arr.includes( winningCombos[i][0] )
                &&
            arr.includes( winningCombos[i][1] )
                &&
            arr.includes( winningCombos[i][2] )
    ) {
        console.log("There's a winner");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Please post the exact code you used. Also, did you check the console for errors?

Comment: Without seeing your HTML and exact Javascript it is going to be difficult to help you.